# Find all Matrices $A$ such that $A^2 +2A = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

B = 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
23 & -10\\
30 & -12\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The hint is to use eigenvectors and eigenvalues, so I diagonalized it into

P = 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac 12 & \frac 23 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
lambda = 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0\\
0 &8 \end{bmatrix}$$

but I don't know where to take it from here. I've looked at the similar problems on here, but none seem to really break down how exactly I can use then eigenvalues/ eigenvectors to help me.

Comment: Notice that $(A+I)^2 = B+I$ where $I$ is the identity, so try to find the square root of $B+I$.